# AngularJS / jQuery sending POST data

Tags: jquery, angularjs, post

I need to send data to an API that (for some weird reason) expects this {'user_uid: '22222'}, literally.

Im trying to do it with jQuery like this:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://api.com/api/',
    'user_id': '2222'

    success: function(result) {
       console.log(result);
       if(result.error){

       }else{

       }
    },

    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
       console.log(xhr.status);
       console.log(thrownError);
    },
 });
```

And with AngularJS:

```
 $http.post('https://api.com/api', {'user_id': '2222'})
 .success(function(data) {
```

}

Weird thing, if I try to do it in Postman, I need to use 'raw' query and enter:
{'user_id': '22222'}

But if I use form-data it fails

Can some point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `'user_id': '2222'` <-- invalid statement

Comment: Your jQuery example is going to throw a syntax error regardless. You should double check the documentation on how create AJAX calls. If you need a literal string of characters, you should specify plain text. Likewise, if you're trying to send JSON data, you should stringify it properly, and again specify your data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have inserted this in the comment but it would be difficult to read the code.

I am suspecting that the API needs a stringified input. Can you try:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://api.com/api/',
    data: JSON.stringify({'user_id': '2222'}),

    success: function(result) {
       console.log(result);
       if(result.error) {

       } else {

       }
    },

    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
       console.log(xhr.status);
       console.log(thrownError);
    },
 });
```

Comment: tried: data: JSON.stringify({'user_id': '222222'}), same error :(

Comment: Hi there, worked with this: JSON.stringify({ "user_id": "100006" } how can I emulate that in AngularJS

Comment: That gives me this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30034835/angularjs-send-post-data-like-jquery?noredirect=1#comment48186116_30034835

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
$http({
  url: 'customUrl',
  method: 'POST',
  data: JSON.stringify({ "user_id": "100006" }),
  headers: { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
  }
}).then(function (success) {
  return success;
}).catch(function (e) {
  throw e;
});
```

Comment: Im trying: $http.post('https://api.urlrl.giftapi', {"user_id": "2222" }) but it says:
o 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. This is working with Jquery ajax call

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) header. You should read more about CORS.

Comment: Same behaviour described here : http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/http-no-access-control-allow-origin-problem-on-post/5625

Comment: CORS is enabled server-side, header: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
And Jquery works with the same URL, dont know why Angular doesen't

Comment: Unknown data type may raise CORS issues. Try to force jsonp in the angular call ? (The ajax call may put an implicit data type.)

Comment: How can I force it? im doing $http.post('https://api.url.gift/api, {"user_id": "22222" }).success ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76905/discussion-between-jbigman-and-mdv).