# AngularJS send POST data like Jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, post

im need to replicate this Jquery ajax functionality:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://api.url.gift/api',
    data: JSON.stringify({ "user_id": "100006" }),
    success: function(result) {
       console.log("asd");
       console.log(result);
    },

    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
       console.log(xhr.status);
       console.log(thrownError);
    },
 });
```

Which works fine, but when I do this in AngularJS:

var myData = JSON.stringify({"user_id": "100006" });

```
  $http({
     url: 'https://api.ecosquared.gift/things/cards/received_byme',
     method: 'POST',
     data: myData,
     headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'},
  }).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
     console.log(data);
  }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     console.log(data);
  });
```

I get:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.url.gift/api. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://url.gift' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.
```

One weird thing, if I dont send data parameter, the request goes trough and that error dont raises, but of course the API dont return the data I expect.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Simple, this is a CORS request which the server specifically has to enable for you by adding the aforementioned header. If you don't have access to the servercode take a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: Server headers are in place, post request returns this: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * . As I mentioned, the SAME Jquery ajax request works fine, but Angular doesen't

Comment: Could you copy paste the full response?

Comment: The question already have the full browser response.

Comment: More important would be the request headers being sent.

Comment: console.log of headers returns this: function (c){a||(a=Xc(b));return c?(c=a[z(c)],void 0===c&&(c=null),c):a}

Comment: what if you remove `'Content-Type'` from headers?

Comment: same error, tried everything :(

Answer (score 1):

Try sending data without converting it to a JSON string and without the quotations:

`var myData = ({user_id: 100006 });`

assuming you user_id is a integer

Comment: Same error, on Jquery had to convert the data to string to get it working

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't resolve it with Angular, had to implement NodeJS and do this:

```
request.post('https://api.url.com/api',
                 {body: JSON.stringify({"user_id": "222" })}, function (error, response, body) {
console.log(body);
});
```

And then consume it with AngularJS.